# How to know if comma separates params or is part of arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, short-circuiting, arrow-functions

I've been messing around with using the comma in short-circuit operations:

```
let component = { on: (p1, p2, p3) => console.log(p1, p2, p3) };
    component.on('something', () => console.log('what do'), '???');
```

It seems ambiguous whether `'???'` is a parameter or not

Is there some sort of rule about this?

Thanks!

---

The [order of operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) doesn't seem to help, since it doesn't describe params

Comment: The ECMAScript specification includes a formal grammar which describes how things like this should be parsed. I don't recall the exact rules, but commas tend to be very "low-precedence", usually applying to outer/large groups. In this case, the comma is outside of the arrow function.

Comment: That's probably why folks encourage the use of curly braces with arrow functions, e.g. () => { component.off('something'); }

Comment: @JeremyBanks It's actually inside of the arrow function

Comment: I don't think you're correct. Look at `Array.of('something', () => 1, 2).length` -- it evaluates to 3, because there are 3 arguments to `Array.of` -- the `2` goes out there, not inside the arrow function

Comment: '???' is an argument to `component.on`

Comment: kinda of like the `if` statement to me, you add curly braces if there's more than 1 lines after the if` statement. In this case, adding curly braces when there's more than one argument can help to clear the confusion.

Comment: @AnthonyC I tend to use `if (true) a = 1, b = 2;` very frequently!!

Comment: @neaumusic, still in one line, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specification defines the precedence of the operators, that's how you can know.

> [**12.16 - Comma Operator ( , )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-comma-operator)
>
> ```
> Expression[In, Yield]:
>     AssignmentExpression[?In, ?Yield]
>     Expression[?In, ?Yield] , AssignmentExpression[?In, ?Yield]
> ```
>
> [**14.2 - Arrow Function Definitions**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions)
>
> ```
> ConciseBody[In]:
>     [lookahead ≠ {]AssignmentExpression[?In]
>     {FunctionBody}
> ```

The concise body of an arrow function must be an *AssignmentExpression*, which can't directly contain commas. But the comma operator can separate different *AssignmentExpression*s.

If you want to make it clear what you are doing, add parentheses:

```js
console.log( (() => 2), 3 );
console.log( (() => 2, 3) );
console.log( () => (2, 3) );
```

Comment: so, why post a *** answer - at least post a *** link to the relevant *** section of the *** manual :p

Comment: @JaromandaX done. Not sure why I got so many downvotes, the question only asks if there is some way to know, not what is the way to know. Adding it anyways.

Comment: @Oriol I don't know why people are hating on this. This is the answer I was looking for